# How to bind a string to scope var within the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova, ionic-view

I want to bind a string to a scope var which will get its value by user input in an input field inside a view.
So that the string concatenated to the scope var value should display in another div in the view.

It should be something like that:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="userInput" placeholder="Enter your input..."/><br>
<div>{{ "Hello" + userInput}}</div>
```

But the problem here is that the word "Hello" displays already before the user input is made. I want to display it together with the value of the scope var when the user input it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use numerous different approaches ...  `ng-if` or use a ternary in expression are two of them

```
<div ng-if="userInput">{{ "Hello" + userInput}}</div>
```

Or

```
<div>{{userInput ?  "Hello" + userInput :''}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Name: <input ng-model="userInput" placeholder="Enter your input..."/><br>
<div ng-show="!!userInput">{{ "Hello" + userInput}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your own `filter` say `ifEmpty` as in below:

```
angular.module('app').filter('ifEmpty', function() {
    return function(input, defaultValue) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(input) || input === null || input === '') {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return "Hello "+input;
    }
});
```

and then use it as

```
<div>{{ userInput | ifEmpty:''}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ng-if` on the user input.

```
<p ng-if="userInput">Hello {{userInput}}</p>
```